# JavaFX how to change the color of arrows in Spinner?

Tags: java, javafx, spinner

How can i change the color of the small arrow in the JavaFX Spinner not the entire button-arrow just the small arrow inside the button?

Is there any library for JavaFX Spinner like JFoenix ?

[image: Details in picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be with CSS. And when it comes to CSS with JavaFX it helps to read the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#spinner) which tells you the styleclasses and substructures of various JavaFX nodes.

In this case, you can do:

```
.spinner .increment-arrow-button .increment-arrow {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}

.spinner .decrement-arrow-button .decrement-arrow {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

Then add the stylesheet to the `Scene` that the `Spinner` belongs to. This will change the arrows (which are `Region`s) to have a background with the color red.

Comment: Is there any library for JavaFX Spinner like JFoenix ?